# Apple Mapkit calculateETAWithCompletionHandler loop through array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, mapkit

I am making an application where when you click a button it populates a tableview with all of the Users and their estimated ETA from you. I keep running into an issue when I'm looping through my users and getting their location it doesn't make the Array in the same order that its looping through and therefore the times become all mixed up. I've tried several different ways of looping through them but it seems like when it gets the directions.calculateETA section it is delayed and runs at different times. Can anyone help me run through this efficiently so the loop doesn't run out of order?

```
for user in usersArray {

    var userLocations:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: user["location"].latitude, longitude: user["location"].longitude)

    ETARequest(userLocations)

}

func ETARequest(destination:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()

    if let currentLocation = self.manager.location?.coordinate {

        request.source =  MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: currentLocation, addressDictionary: nil))

        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destination, addressDictionary: nil))

        request.transportType = .Automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

        directions.calculateETAWithCompletionHandler({ ( response, error) in

            if error == nil {

                if let interval = response?.expectedTravelTime  {

                    print(self.formatTimeInterval(interval))

                    self.durationArray.insert(self.formatTimeInterval(interval), atIndex: 0)

                    if self.durationArray.count == self.allUsers.count {

                        print(self.durationArray)

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }

                }

            } else {

                print("Error Occurred")
            }

        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `calculateETAWithCompletionHandler` makes a network request. It's an asynchronous function, so you can't assume that all your calls to it will return in the same order you sent them. Here's one solution to this problem:

If you have a `user` object with an optional `duration` property, you can refactor your `ETARequest` method to take one as input:

```
func ETARequest(destination:CLLocationCoordinate2D, user: UserType) {
    //Do stuff...
}
```

Then, in the completion handler block you pass to `calculateETAWithCompletionHandler`, you can replace `self.durationArray.insert(self.formatTimeInterval(interval), atIndex: 0)` with `user.duration = self.formatTimeInterval(interval)`. (You can still have a counter to determine when all requests have finished.)

This way, each user will have a duration associated with it, and you can display them accordingly by looping through your users in the desired order.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: This Worked Amazingly. I created a custom class. An array of users downloaded from my database. For each user in my database I added their information to my custom class. 

     user.name 
     user. location
     user.toUserDistance

Then I looped through them and assigned the user to the user: UserType function. Worked perfect!